# WP7: Creating a non-network toast-like message inside an App?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, messagebox, toast

Okay so the title might sound a bit confusing, but here's what I want to do:
In the app im developing, I want to display a message to the user when he clicks a button, and then hide the message again shortly hereafter - Just like a toast message in Android.

At the moment I use a MessageBox, but the fact that the user has to press an OK button to hide it again is anoying, so I was hoping there would be a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ToastRequestTrigger` from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) as described in the [patterns & practices WP7 Developer Guide](http://wp7guide.codeplex.com/) to display non-network toast messages. The [Coding4Fun Library](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) also provides a `ToastPrompt` class, which performs the ssame function.

Comment: I've been messing around with this for an hour now, and I have no idea how to use it. I've added the Prism references to my project, but how do I create a toast and display it? What I read around the web just confuses me.

Comment: Have you read/try this? [ToastPrompt on WinPhoGeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Toast-Prompt-in-depth). The first code snippet there tells pretty much everything about how to use it.

Comment: I dismissed the coding4fun tools at first because I thought I would run into some licensing and copyright issues, but turns out I wont. So yeah, I've tried it now and it works perfectly. Thanks both of you!